# Тормозит приложение , при установки фоном картинки (full hd)

Tags: android

Установил фоном картинку full hd качества и после этого, приложение стало жутко тормозить, fps 5 наверное.
P.S. Приложение выводит список данных из базы данных,с обычным фоном, все замечательно (RGB или что то подобное), поставил картинку в стиле и все, трындец...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private Cursor c;
    public ArrayList mDataSet = new ArrayList();
    public ArrayList mDataSet1 = new ArrayList();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG,"onCreate start");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        MyDatabase db = new MyDatabase(this);
        c = db.getEmployees();

        MyTask mt = new MyTask();
        mt.execute();

        Log.d(TAG,"onCreate finished");
    }


    private ArrayList<String> getDataSet() {
        Log.d(TAG,"start getDataset");

        c.moveToFirst();
        for (int i = 1; i < c.getCount();i++) {
            mDataSet.add(c.getString(1));
            c.moveToNext();
        }
        return mDataSet;

    }

    private ArrayList<String> getDataSet1() {
        Log.d(TAG,"start getDataset1");

        c.moveToFirst();
        for (int i = 1; i < c.getCount();i++) {
            mDataSet1.add(c.getString(2));
            c.moveToNext();
        }
        return mDataSet1;

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();


        switch (id) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Пункт настроек в разработке", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


    class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            return null;
        }



        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            ArrayList<String> myDataset = getDataSet();
            ArrayList<String> myDataset1 = getDataSet1();


            RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
            if (mRecyclerView != null) {
                mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            }
            RecyclerAdapter mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(myDataset, myDataset1);
            if (mRecyclerView != null) {
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            }
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: что делается в приложении? покажите код/разметку

Comment: а зачем пихать FHD? загрузите картинку под размеры фона. разницы не заметите. У вас это картинка просто отъела всю память.

Comment: С кодом вроде все нормально. До этого не было, не одного лага, как только поставил фон в стилях, все с этого и началось. Да и как картинка весом 1 мегабайт, может так нагружать телефон??

Comment: Имеет роль не вес картинки, а его размер в пикселях и сколько тратится байт на пиксель  -> 1920*1080*4 (RGBA_8888) = 8 мегабайт памяти... на фон....

Comment: @Chaynik Какие варианты? уменьшить разрешение картинки?

Comment: Изменить размер картинки естественно.. сделайте нарезку, под разные экраны, на экране 640 на 480 FHD очевидно не нужно. или уберите вообще.

Comment: Вариант такой вам необходимо отрендерить картинки в зависимости от экрана устройства - это стандартная практика и таких примеров очень много.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei приведите пример, ищу и ищу, а нахожу только работу с иконками.